# Parallel Structure: negative comparative

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Consider the following sentence:

> Frank will not be honored for dedicating his time to orphans, as Fred will not be honored for devoting his life to the poor.

A better way to phrase this might be:

> Frank will not be honored for dedicating his time to orphans, any more than Fred will be honored for devoting his life to the poor.

But what is the wrong with the first? Or is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It's fine, though it might be better to rewrite *as* as *just as* to preclude the reading *because*.

Comment: 'As' also has the meaning 'because', which works here (allowing for suitable context). 'Just as' removes the ambiguity.

Comment: You can also use _much as_ to suggest parallism.

Comment: @user87755: The parallelism is not at issue; they are indeed parallel. The problem is that both clauses are ambiguous. The first one could continue "Rather, Frank will be honored for his skills at ping-pong." Or it could continue; "Rather, Frank will not receive any honors at all." Those correspond to two different ways of understanding ("readings") of that clause; and the other clause has the same structure and similar ambiguities. Since they're conjoined and compared, they both have to have the same reading; but that still means it's too complicated to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Looking again at your original sentence—

> Frank will not be honored for dedicating his time to orphans, as Fred will not be honored for devoting his life to the poor.

I am struck by the oddness of the author's desire to compare the fates of Frank and Fred at all. If the point of the original sentence is to establish causality with regard to Frank's not being honored—specifically, Fred will not be honored for his work, and therefore Frank will not be either—the author could avoid the ambiguity over the intended sense of *as* by replacing it with *because* (as Edwin Ashworth and StoneyB point out in comments above):

> Frank will not be honored for dedicating his time to orphans, because Fred will not be honored for devoting his life to the poor [and it would be unfair to honor one but not the other].

But if we are supposed to interpret *as* to mean "in the same way that" (or as StoneyB suggests, to mean "just as"), I can't see what the author of the example has gained by setting up the sentence as a comparison. Its rather like saying "X won't happen in the same way that Y won't happen." I suppose you could say that everything that doesn't happen doesn't happen in the same way, but that's a rather mind-boggling way to put it. Grammatically the construction is fine, by I see no advantage in using that wording when you could say, far more straightforwardly,

> Frank will not be honored for dedicating his time to orphans, and Fred will not be honored for devoting his life to the poor.

or perhaps

> Although Frank has dedicated his time to orphans and Fred has devoted his life to the poor, neither will be honored.

If the author intends to say something more penetrating—such as that Frank's time dedicated to orphans isn't nearly as impressive as Fred's life devoted to the poor, and that therefore it makes perfect sense that, since Fred isn't going to be honored, Frank shouldn't be either—that idea needs a better vehicle of expression than the original sentence's equating of the two men's lack of honors.

Comment: It could be a sarcastic reference to the men, indicating how Frank shut down orphanages and Fred lived a life of luxury on his yacht.

Comment: Or perhaps Fred an Frank were both orphans and irrationally considered themselves poor, and actually dedicated their entire lives to self-aggrandizement.